# How to extract certain fields from encrypted JSON string in Swift?

Tags: ios, json, swift, applepay

I am integrating `Apple Pay` into my application. I have a service written in Java which actually takes the encrypted blob sent from my `iOS` App and decrypts it and sends it back.

I am facing two problems here:

1. Bigger Problem - My service only consumes XML payload and hence I need to convert the `JSON` payload to `XML` payload in my `iOS` app which I am not sure how to do.
2. Smaller Problem - I am trying to extract the fields from this encrypted `JSON` payload and print it out on the console.

Example:

```
let jsonBody = payment.token.paymentData
print("jsonBody = \(jsonBody)")    !!! WORKS (prints encrypted data) !!!
```

However, I am not able to extract other parameters that are present in the paymentData dictionary as per the following link
  https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/PassKit/Reference/PaymentTokenJSON/PaymentTokenJSON.html

Example:

```
let paymentDataDict:[String:String] = payment.token.paymentData
for (key, value) in paymentDataDict {
    print("Dictionary key \(key) -  Dictionary value \(value)")
}

Error: Cannot convert value of type 'NSData' to specified type '[String : String]'
```

Source:

```
 /*
     * This is the first method to be called by the passkit framework once the encrypted blob is received from the apple server.
     * Our implementation of the call back function below is calling payment service to decrypt the encrypted blob.
     * It then proceeds to call processPayment method to send this data down to payment service for authorization.
    */
    func paymentAuthorizationViewController(controller: PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController, didAuthorizePayment payment: PKPayment, completion: (PKPaymentAuthorizationStatus) -> Void) {
        let decryptUrl = NSURL(string: "http://lvsdevwsv04-01.us.gspt.net:1801/public-api-service/v1.0/stores/TMSUS/payments/decryptblob.xml")  // Decryption URL
        let decryptRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: decryptUrl!)
        decryptRequest.HTTPMethod = "POST"
        decryptRequest.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        decryptRequest.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
        let jsonBody = payment.token.paymentData
        print("jsonBody = \(jsonBody)")

        //ERROR IN THE BELOW LINE
        let paymentDataDict:[String:String] = payment.token.paymentData
        for (key, value) in paymentDataDict {
            print("Dictionary key \(key) -  Dictionary value \(value)")
        }

        decryptRequest.HTTPBody = jsonBody
        let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(decryptRequest) {data, response, error in
            guard error == nil && data != nil else {
                print("error=\(error)")
                return
            }
            if let httpStatus = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse where httpStatus.statusCode != 200 {
                print("statuscode should be 200, but is \(httpStatus.statusCode)")
                print("response = \(response)")
            } else {
                let responseString = NSString(data: data!, en

    //code removed for brevity
```

Answer (score 0):

I was finally able to print the encrypted string on the console after converting it to NSString object. Here is the code snippet that worked for me after some minor changes.

```
    let encryptedPaymentData = payment.token.paymentData
    let paymentMethod = payment.token.paymentMethod
    let txId = payment.token.transactionIdentifier
    print("paymentMethod = \(paymentMethod)")
    print("txId = \(txId)")
    let decryptedPaymentData:NSString! = NSString(data: encryptedPaymentData, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    print("decryptedPaymentData = \(decryptedPaymentData)")
```